# Why is this code not redirecting to this url?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I made a script to automatically redirect to English Wikipedia and Wiktionary. However, my script doesn't work anymore after I added the functionality to Wiktionary.

```
// @match        https://*.wikipedia.org/*
// @exclude      https://en.wikipedia.org/*
// Change the above to fit your language

// @match        https://*.wiktionary.org/*
// @exclude      https://en.wiktionary.org/*
// Change the above to fit your language

// Now works with wiktionary!

// @grant        none
// @icon         https://i.imgur.com/A75OqHr.png
// ==/UserScript==

if (location.hostname == "*.wikipedia.org"){
location.hostname = "en.wikipedia.org" //change me to your language
}

if (location.hostname == "*.wiktionary.org"){
    location.hostname = "en.wiktionary.org" //change me to your language
}
```

*Note: I left out some of the metadata for anti-doxxing purposes.

Comment: `*.wikipedia.org` is not a possible hostname. `==` doesn't do pattern matching, it looks for an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are looking for,

```
window.location.href = "URL_YOU_WANT_TO_REDIRECT_TO";
```

Do check it once whether your 'if' condition is running properly or not, in case this is not exactly what you were looking for, do let me know

Answer (score 0):

**==** doesn't do pattern matching. So it's not gonna help you.

If you wanna include all subdomains under wikipedia.org, you can just use the **String includes() Method.** You can read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp).

So this can be solved even without pattern matching just by using **includes()** method on the string like below:

```
if (location.hostname.includes("wikipedia.org")){
   location.href = "en.wikipedia.org" //change me to your language
}

if (location.hostname.includes("wiktionary.org")){
   location.href = "en.wiktionary.org" //change me to your language
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I found that the lines 2 and 6 were bugged and used location.hostname = instead

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for a string with the content of `*.wikipedia.org` and `*.wiktionary.org`. It also seems like the logic you intend to use would result in a infinite loop.

You could take advantage of the not equals operator `!==` like in this example to prevent this and also only check for the spesific site you wish to redirect too.

```js
const redirectToCorrectPage = url => location.hostname !== url ? location.hostname = url : null;

redirectToCorrectPage("en.wikipedia.org")
redirectToCorrectPage("en.wiktionary.org")
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the following:

```
// @match        https://*.wikipedia.org/*
// @exclude      https://en.wikipedia.org/*
```

There is no need to check again the `location.hostname` since above will run on all `wikipedia.org` subdomains (as well as `https://wikipedia.org/`) except `en.wikipedia.org`.

Now a basic redirector user-script would be like this:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name          My Script
// @match         https://*.wikipedia.org/*
// @exclude       https://en.wikipedia.org/*
// @run-at        document-start
// ==/UserScript==

location.hostname = 'en.wiktionary.org';
```

`@run-at        document-start` would prevent the unwanted page from loading needlessly.